# Why is the Bernoulli distribution not discrete?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, bernoulli-distribution

## Problem

> In any basic probability course, we learn that the Bernoulli distribution is a **discrete** probability distribution. However, when using **measure theory**, it seems that it is actually not.

## Context

I could not find any measure-theoretic description of a Bernoulli random variable and distribution, so I had to come up with one, but this makes the Bernoulli distribution not discrete.

Let $([0, 1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \text{Leb})$ be a probability space, where $\mathcal{B}([0, 1])$ denotes the Borel sigma-algebra on $[0, 1]$ and $\text{Leb}$ the Lebesgue measure on it. Given $p\in[0, 1]$ define the Bernoulli random variable as $X_p:[0, 1]\to\{0, 1\}$
$$
X_p(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
    1 & \omega \leq p \\
    0 & \omega > p
\end{cases}\qquad \forall\, \omega\in[0, 1].
$$
The distribution of this random variable is $\mu_p = \text{Leb} \circ X^{-1}_p$ is a probability measure on $(\{0, 1\}, \mathcal{P}(\{0, 1\}))$, where $\mathcal{P}(\{0, 1\})$ is the power set on $\{0, 1\}$ and the distribution can be written as
$$
\mu_p(\mathsf{A}) = \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}} p^x(1-p)^{1-x} \delta_x(\mathsf{A}) \qquad \forall\, \mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{P}(\{0, 1\}).
$$
Clearly, this distribution is dominated by the counting measure $\mu_p \ll d\text{count}$
$$
d\text{count}(\mathsf{A}) = 
\begin{cases}
    |\mathsf{A}| & \mathsf{A} \text{ is finite.} \\
    \infty & \mathsf{A} \text{ is infinite.}
\end{cases}
$$
However, $X_p$ is **not** a discrete random variable, since a random variable is discrete if **its pre-image is countable**. In this case, $X^{-1}(\{0, 1\}) = [0, 1]$ and this is **uncountable**. Am I missing something?

> Notice that one could argue that the base probability space I should use, should not be  $([0, 1], \mathcal{P}([0, 1]), \text{Leb})$ but rather any countable/finite measurable space with a normalized counting measure. However, this would make it impossible to have Bernoulli random variables for $p\in[0,1]$ **irrational**.

Comment: It is completely unnecessary to use $[0, 1]$ as the sample space here, you can just use the two-element set $\{ 0, 1 \}$ with the probability measure $\mu(0) = 1 - p, \mu(1) = p$, and there's no issue with $p$ being irrational. Also your definition of a discrete random variable is incorrect; it should not depend on the choice of sample space.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So I could use $(\{0, 1\}, \mathcal{P}(\{0, 1\}))$ as my base measurable space and then what reference measure would I put there? In order for $X$ to be a random variable, its "input" space must be a **probability** space, not just a measure space. What is the correct definition of a discrete random variable, in measure-theoretic terms?

Comment: I would define a random variable $X$ to be discrete if its distribution measure (I.e. the push forward of the probability measure $\mu$ from the sample space along $X$), is atomic, ie concentrated on a countable set.  I think that’s a standard definition.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to understand what is the input space of the Bernoulli random variable. In other words, the sample space. My understanding is that to define a random variable I need a **probability** space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, a **measurable** space $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and a measurable function $X:\Omega\to\mathsf{X}$, whose distribution is $P_X = \mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$. My question is then now, what is a good choice for $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ here?

Comment: @Physics_Student: the probability measure is the unique measure satisfying $\mu(0) = 1 - p, \mu(1) = p$, there's no difficulty with this. M W's definition of a discrete random variable looks fine to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A random variable $X$ is discrete if it takes values in a discrete set (so a finite set or a set with the discrete topology).

Discreteness is about the image, not the pre-image.

Comment: I think usually a random variable taking values on say, $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$ would be considered discrete as well, in which case the topological discreteness criterion would be too strong, but its possible terminology varies.

Comment: @MW do you have examples of such random variables? Also, is there a benefit in considering those random variable having a discrete distribution?

Comment: @Physics_Student you can certainly define a random variable to have probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of taking the value $0$ and $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ of taking the value $\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n$.  As for a benefit of considering such a variable to be discrete, the point is from a measure theoretic standpoint it doesn't really matter that it has a limit point, its distribution is still described by an atomic measure, so expectations, variances, etc are still computed with a weighted sum.

Comment: @MW aah I see, interesting. What would you say is then the most general definition of a discrete distribution/random variable?

Comment: @Physics_Student I would say it’s probably the one I gave in the comment to original post, where the push forward of the prob measure from the sample space is atomic.  Note this doesn’t require the random variable to be real valued either.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that definition of discrete random variable is a good one (countable preimage). Countable *image* is more like it, although still not quite right. Note that, since we allow an enormous variety of general measure spaces to model the "same" random variable (one with the same distribution) - in particular we could also model a Bernoulli variable with a finite measure space - such a definition is not even well-defined.

A measure (in total generality) is said to be discrete if it is a countable weighted sum of Dirac measures. A random variable is discrete if its induced distribution measure is discrete. This is clearly true here, since $\mu=(1-p)\delta(0)+p\delta(1)$.

Comment: In Probability and Stochastics, I have found the following definition. Let $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space and $\mathsf{D}\subset\mathsf{E}$ be a **countable** subset of it. Let $m(x) > 0$ for any $x\in\mathsf{D}$. Then
$$
\mu(\mathsf{A}) = \sum_{x\in\mathsf{D}} m(x)\delta_x(\mathsf{A})\qquad \mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{E}
$$
is a measure on $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ and it is called discrete. So you're right, it is a countable weighted sum of Dirac measures.